# Can i install Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop on epyc 7371?

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, initramfs, busybox, cpu-architecture

Can i install Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop on epyc 7371? I tried installing in the usual way but the image from the flash drive loads up to Busybox and initramfs. I also tried installing the Ubuntu hard drive and inserting it into the computer with Epyc 7371 and booting was slowed down by a black screen.

Comment: If "*the image from the flash drive*" (the installer?) loads Busybox, that suggests the flash drive has been mis-made or is faulty. If the fully-installed Ubuntu system loads Busybox, that suggests a corrupt filesystem or faulty HDD/SSD. Your description is unclear.

Comment: I was able to install the system from this flash drive on another PC without any problems

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I inserted the Ubuntu flash drive into the USB connector on the chassis, and I should have inserted it into the motherboard.